# Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section httpCookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have added the following to my `web.config` file in my asp.net mvc3, to stop script from accessing the cookies:
`<httpCookies domain="String" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />,` as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  **<httpCookies domain="String" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />**
  <system.web>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

**but when I ran the application it raised the following error:-**
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section httpCookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<httpCookies>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228262.aspx) element is a child node of the `<system.web>` element so you must put it inside:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
    <httpCookies domain="String" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />

    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

...
</system.web>
```